# Can webpart title style in classic pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, css, sitepages, classic-experience

Can we style the all Web part title in SharePoint classic page like below same class?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my observation, web part titles parent `div` on classic experience has below class:

```
ms-webpart-chrome-title
```

& div id like:

```
WebPartWPQ10_ChromeTitle
```

So, you can apply your custom CSS to above class like:

```
<style>

    div.ms-webpart-chrome-title {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: lightskyblue
    }
    
    div.ms-webpart-chrome-title h2, div.ms-webpart-chrome-title h2 a {
        color: white !important
    }

</style>
```

OR:

```
<style>

    div[id$='_ChromeTitle'] {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: lightskyblue
    }
    
    div[id$='_ChromeTitle'] h2, div[id$='_ChromeTitle'] h2 a {
        color: white !important
    }

</style>
```

Add above code in script editor web part on classic page. You can change other CSS properties as per your requirements.

**Output**:

[image]